# Is All for One more powerful than All Might?

Tags: my-hero-academia

The Ultra Analysis stats give All for One perfect stats in everything, 6/6 S+ for power, speed, intelligence and technique, when All Might only has 6/6 S+ in power and speed, and 6/6 S in intelligence and technique. Is All for One more powerful than All Might?

Comment: related: [How is "One for All" stronger than "All for One"?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/46658/how-is-one-for-all-stronger-than-all-for-one?rq=1)

Answer (score -1):

Depends, if you take the fact that All Might defeated All for One twice then no, All for One is weaker but still, All For One weakened All Might to the point where everyone knew his skinny form. But if you take their quirks against each other, All For One can actually win (without protag power)

Answer (score -1):

I think One For All is stronger.

Think of it like this: All For One is definitely weaker like All Might. Supporting this fact is that he still hasn’t healed, and is wearing a life-support mask. When they fought the first time, he messed up All Might's stomach really badly. In the second fight, All For One only held him back with his hands.

And when class A and class B were attacked on the campsite, Muscular lost to Midoriya who has One For All. When Midoriya passed by Spinner during the attack, he claimed that Muscular was the second or first strongest in the group.

Dabi claims that Tomura was weak for sending a bunch of rookie villains and that Dabi brought a bunch of hard-to-defeat villains.

Therefore, I think One For All is stronger.

Comment: The question is asking about All For One and All Might, not One For All. Thus, looks like the only relevant point is the 2nd paragraph, but it's unclear who is stronger/weaker from this answer.